# Reading large file in Java -- Java heap space

Tags: java, file, file-io

I'm reading a large tsv file (~40G) and trying to prune it by reading line by line and print only certain lines to a new file. However, I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2894)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:117)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:532)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:323)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:379)
```

Below is the main part of the code. I specified the buffer size to be 8192 just in case. Doesn't Java clear the buffer once the buffer size limit is reached? I don't see what may cause the large memory usage here. I tried to increase the heap size but it didn't make any difference (machine with 4GB RAM). I also tried flushing the output file every X lines but it didn't help either. I'm thinking maybe I need to make calls to the GC but it doesn't sound right.

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot. 
BTW - I know I should call trim() only once, store it, and then use it.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("A-B");
...
...
static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile),"UTF-8"), 8192);
   PrintStream output = new PrintStream(outputFile, "UTF-8");

   String line = reader.readLine();
   while(line!=null){
        String[] fields = line.split("\t");
        if( set.contains(fields[0].trim()+"-"+fields[1].trim()) )
            output.println((fields[0].trim()+"-"+fields[1].trim()));

        line = reader.readLine();
   }

output.close();

}
```

Comment: Does it print any results at all? Does it always blow up at the same point?  You're sure it's actually reading the file a line at a time i.e. it's identifying the line-ends OK and there are no lines long enough to cause heap to blow?  Daft questions to ask I know...

Comment: What -Xmx setting are you using on the JVM? By default Java won't use all the available RAM on the machine unless you specify using the -Xmx arg.

Comment: @bstick12: having more memory for your application can hide some important design mistake that will pop up later. In 99.99% cases, the default memory is enough and if it isn't then you're doing something wrong

Comment: "In 99.99% cases, the default memory is enough and if it isn't then you're doing something wrong" So how do you explain most production server and to some extents many java app do increase the defaults values ? 99.99% of theses are doing something wrong?

Answer (score 17):

Most likely, what's going on is that the file does not have line terminators, and so the reader just keeps growing it's StringBuffer unbounded until it runs out of memory.

The solution would be to read a fixed number of bytes at a time, using the 'read' method of the reader, and then look for new lines (or other parsing tokens) within the smaller buffer(s).

Comment: This would probably be a good place for the NIO package- he'd need all of the performance he can get to process 40GB or so of text data.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now because I noticed that doesn't matter the max heap size I set, the final output file size is always the same. So I suspect that there's one line somewhere that causes the trouble. I'm now checking it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user431336: Also, don't forget to close your PrintStream... your example leaves it open when you terminate the method.

Comment: @Dataknife the PrintStream? I do close it once the loop terminates.

Comment: Corrupt file with missing line terminators would be first thing to check -- I had exactly the same situation while reading 4Gb ASCII file. Try command "tail <your file_name>" to see if it prints and exists correctly. For corrupt file it will be stuck without exiting

Answer (score 3):

Are you certain the "lines" in the file are separated by newlines?

Comment: Somewhere in the file this is probably the problem.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 theories:

- The input file is not UTF-8 but some indeterminate binary format that results in extremely long lines when read as UTF-8.
- The file contains some extremely long "lines" ... or no line breaks at all.
- Something else is happening in code that you are not showing us; e.g. you are adding new elements to `set`.

---

To help diagnose this:

- Use some tool like `od` (on UNIX / LINUX) to confirm that the input file really contains valid line terminators; i.e. CR, NL, or CR NL.
- Use some tool to check that the file is valid UTF-8.
- Add a static line counter to your code, and when the application blows up with an OOME, print out the value of the line counter.
- Keep track of the longest line seen so far, and print that out as well when you get an OOME.

---

For the record, your slightly suboptimal use of `trim` will have no bearing on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you are running out of heap space *during* a garbage collection. The Hotspot JVM uses a parallel collector by default, which means that your application can possibly allocate objects faster than the collector can reclaim them. I have been able to cause an OutOfMemoryError with supposedly only 10K live (small) objects, by rapidly allocating and discarding.

You can try instead using the old (pre-1.5) serial collector with the option `-XX:+UseSerialGC`. There are several other "extended" [options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) that you can use to tune collection.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try removing the `String[] fields` declaration out of the loop. As you are creating a new array in every loop. You can just reuse the old one right?

Comment: He's not creating anything. He's declaring a variable that holds a reference to an array of String objects (returned by `split()`). Since its required scope is only in the loop, it's perfectly fine to declare it there.

Comment: The String[] is a local variable within the scope of the loop and any allocated memory for the array will be garbage collected by the JVM.

Comment: @BrianRoach Correct me if I'm wrong, but surely a `String[]` is being created every time `split()` is called? I get where @Shaunak is coming from - if a `String[]` is being created (and GC'd) on every loop, would it not be more efficient to declare it before the loop, re-use it on each iteration, then set it to null (for GC) after the loop? (I'm sure this is the way it was taught back in the J2ME days!...)